# Skype 4.2.0.11 keeps restarting after quit

Tags: command-line, skype

Skype on Ubuntu 12.04 keeps on starting up after I shut it off. If I'm not going to touch Skype after reboot it will not bother me, but just one start is enough to begin with never-ending loop of Skype login windows. Skype itself appear to work without any problems.

I installed Skype by following these lines in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype && sudo apt-get -f install
```

I reinstalled it trough the terminal as well thinking it would help solving the problem, but it didn't. I would love to restore total control over this application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try to fix the problem bei reinstalling skype, quit the application (or in your case, don't start after login).
Then uninstall it by following command:

```
apt-get remove --purge skype
```

After that, just reinstall and try again:

```
apt-get install skype
```

Comment: Did this help? Please set it as solution.